# ListView Adapter error to load in other xml

Tags: android, xml, listview

I need create a mediaplayer in the main_activity.xml and I need show a list songs in the other xml, but when I try use the adapter I will get an error
this is a example trying with a simple array string but doesn't work

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] phones={"Alcatel,Motorola,G2,Iphone"};
    ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.real,phones);
    ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Where "Lista" is the ListView and "real" is the other xml, Lista is in real

Comment: Can u share your error log

Comment: There is no log whe compile, the error happen when open the appp

Comment: Can u post that run time error

Comment: https://puu.sh/umn9y/44c2d16352.png

Comment: @FelipePeña **Kindly go through my youtube url where you can get idea about it https://youtu.be/knLoziZ0XWw**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pass resource id(TextView's id which is created in your xml) also in constructor like

```
ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects);//int textViewResourceId
```

e.g.

```
ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.real, R.id.textview, phones);// R.id.text is your textview which is created in your xml
```

See given xml and see textview id, that you have to pass

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:id="@+id/textview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Excuse me Sir, I didn't undertand very well I must create a textview in the other xml togheter the Listview and I must paste the constructor in the MainActivity.java, sorry I am very newier

Comment: Yes I did but where can I put the listview, because in the main xml I can't

Comment: @FelipePeña **Kindly go through my youtube url where you can get idea about it https://youtu.be/knLoziZ0XWw**

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] phones={"Alcatel,Motorola,G2,Iphone"};
    ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.real,R.id.textview,phones);
    ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Try this one (Y)

Comment: what's the difference from my answer?

Comment: there is no difference but if you will changes in code of given question that will be easily understood by asked person. thats why i did changes in their code.

Comment: where is this textview?

Comment: add text view in ur XML file with I'd of R.id.textview